# An error just suddenly appeared in my ionic project stating 'Cannot find name Unknown'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, ionic4

The app has the Google map places search functionality and i tried to use https://github.com/skynet2/ngx-google-places-autocomplete) to implement the auto complete functionality. This error occurred after i installed this plugin. I think the problem is withing the node module files. I installed ionic 4 on my PC but the app was created in ionic 3, everything was fine until now.

The error references to:

> "StepDrive/node_modules/@ionic-native/core/decorators/common.d.ts"
>
> **line 8** export declare function wrapPromise(pluginObj: any, methodName: string, args: any[], opts?: CordovaOptions):
>   Promise;
>
> **line 9 |**/**
>
> **line 10|** * Checks if plugin/cordova is available

Sometimes it comes back as:

> index.js:180 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>       at index.js:180
>       at Object. (index.js:288)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap f7410936e56da4992b49:54)
>       at Object.718 (main.js:2910)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap f7410936e56da4992b49:54)
>       at Object.377 (main.ts:5)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap f7410936e56da4992b49:54)
>       at Object.372 (main.ts:1)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap f7410936e56da4992b49:54)
>       at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap f7410936e56da4992b49:25)

I tried removing the plugin (because i thought it was the issue), restarted my PC and also cloning the project that didn't install the plugin from GitHub but somehow it's still there i don't see many problems that are similar to this one anywhere. Please help i don't know ionic that much to fiddle with the node modules. So I'm thinking it's probably a clash of the app being version 3 and my ionic being version 4.

These are the versions of things i think are of importance:

- ionic@4.12.0 | npm -v: 6.4.1 | Angular CLI: 7.3.9 | Node: 10.15.3 |

If anyone can, please help.

Comment: Try deleting the node_modules folder and run npm install again. Would be great if you added package.json also.

Comment: @Vinaysharma i just reinstalled node modules it's still there

Comment: In the end I updated to "typescript": "3.6.2".